# VB.NET - Adding items to a listview as well as checkboxes and tag property

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

I've got this code which basically loops through a set of folders and subfolders and finds specific file types. And then lists these in a listview. Now, it's intended to list exe and msi files. And I've made it so that these icons can be doubleclicked after they have been listed. I do this by adding the path to the file in it's tag property.

But, my superiors want a checkbox next to each item. So that they can check each item they want installed. And then have a button which runs the path in each tag property one at a time. It's basically the part where I fill the listview with the checkbox, filename of the exe or msi file, tag and the icon that I'm wondering about.

This is the existing code. This includes just a Tile view of the listview.

```
   Public Sub getDirectories(ByVal strFilepath As String, ByVal strFileExtension As String, ByVal objControl As Object)

        'Load first files from the root folder. Then loop each subfolder
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(strFilepath)
        Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles(strFileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories)

        Dim filePath As String
        Dim fileIcon As Icon

        ' For each file in the root folder
        For Each file In aryFi
            If file.Extension = String.Empty Then
            Else
                filePath = GetAssociatedProgram(file.Extension)
                On Error Resume Next

                'Extract icon
                fileIcon = Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath)
                'Add the icon if we haven't got it already
                objControl.StateImageList = Form1.iconList

                If Form1.iconList.Images.ContainsKey(filePath) Then
                Else
                    Form1.iconList.Images.Add(filePath, fileIcon)
                End If
                'Add item to list
                objControl.items.add(file.Name, filePath).Tag = file.DirectoryName
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Basically I call this sub in this way:

```
getDirectories(strProgramLocation, "*.exe", Form1.listViewSupSoftware)
```

And I've found that I can add items to a listview which also contains columns:

```
        Dim tempstr(2) As String
        tempstr(0) = "Name of item"
        tempstr(1) = "Target folder of item"

        Dim tempNode As ListViewItem
        tempNode = New ListViewItem(tempstr)
        Form1.listViewItem.Items.Add(tempNode)
```

But there should be a way of combining these two right? I'm not sure how I can add a checkbox in the first column of the listview? I've already set the Checkbox property of the listview to True. But I could use some pointers here if anyone's got any. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mmm, I don't understand quite well your question. If you already have the listbox you just need to use a CheckedListBox and loop thru all the checked items executing the executable stored into the tag property ...

As I said I'm not sure If I get what you mean ...

Comment: Well, basically I want a listview with three columns. The first should contain a checkbox, second should contain the icon and name of the file, third should contain the filepath to the actual file. And for each file it finds in the loop, I want to add the checkbox, item and icon and path to the file. In each corresponding column.

Comment: Well, to do that you will need to use a grid instead of a listbox because you would need a CheckedListBox which does not accept columns.

Comment: Actually, I just tried to set the CheckBox property of the listview to true. This made each line have it's own checkbox. Now, I had to remove the icon for each line, because the icon seems to replace the checkbox. Dunno how the icon gets set on the same space as the checkbox. I didn't do it through code, so it must be a built in thing. But, removing the icons actually gave me a checkbox for each line, WITH columns as well in the same listview.

Comment: Well, that's another option, of course but then you won't be able to show icons.

Comment: ListView and ListBox are two different animals.